getInstalledRelatedApps() seems to selectively detect installed apps
I am trying to set up a PWA for my website.
There will be 2 places the user will be able to download the PWA.
www.example.com, and www.example.com/chat
I have 2 different manifests with the respective start_urls (example.com and example.com/chat). They also are in different directories.
Homepage is in: statics\homepage\json\example.webmanifest
Chat is in: statics\chat\json\example.webmanifest
When user is in homepage, we will inject the homepage manifest, and when user is in chat we will inject the chat manifest.
I want to make sure that when user has either PWA installed, the existing button to 'install PWA' will open the PWA instead.
To do this, I have given both webmanifest files the same related_applications.
in both homepage\json\example.webmanifest AND chat\json\example.webmanifest
"related_applications": [
        {
            "platform": "webapp",
            "url": "https://example.com/statics/homepage/json/example.webmanifest",
            "id": "homepage"
        },
        {
            "platform": "webapp",
            "url": "https://example.com/statics/chat/json/example.webmanifest",
            "id": "homepage"
        }
    ]

The manifest injection works properly and I can get the user to download my PWA. I use getInstalledRelatedApps() to detect if the PWA is installed, and if it does, I redirect them.
The problem is that if the user installs the PWA on one URL, the other URL does not detect said PWA (getInstalledRelatedApps() returns an empty array).
So for example, if I installed the PWA through www.example.com, and go to www.example.com/chat, the getInstalledRelatedApps() returns an empty array. But, if I go back to www.example.com and call getInstalledRelatedApps(), it will return the installed app correctly.
Is there anything else I need to set up in order to get the behavior I expect from getInstalledRelatedApps()?
I know we are reading two different manifest files in homepage and chat. But chat's manifest has the homepage manifest path inside the related_applications tab.
I can see the related applications in the manifest file doing something like this:
        const manifestUrl = document.querySelector('link[rel="manifest"]')?.getAttribute("href");
        const manifestResponse = await fetch(manifestUrl as string);
        const manifest = await manifestResponse.json();
        const relatedApplications = manifest.related_applications;

And sure enough, there are both related application urls (homepage\json\webmanifest and chat\json\webmanifest).
So I would think getInstalledRelatedApps() should be reading both and going through the installed apps and matching the urls, and when it sees the homepage webmanifest url, it should match it to the installed app url, but this is not the case.
The browser detects that the same PWA applies to both links, because there is also the option for me to open the link in PWA in the search bar.
